# Index column index is just displaying 1's constantly in DAX

Tags: dax

I have a table that shows data for different types of alerts that happen, it looks like this:

```
Time                     ID        status.     timesinceprev(seconds)          index 
22.1.21 04:02:04         12         None                 0                      1
22.1.21 04:24:07         12         low               1320                      1
22.1.21 04:26:04         12         medium            120                       1
......
....
......
......
......
```

I'm not sure why the index column seems to be only showing 1's its quite confusing.

This is what the index column query looks like:

```
index=RANKX(ALL('Time to Action'[ID]),'Time to Action'[timesinceprev])
```

How do I get it so that the index column increments properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `[ID]`

```
RANKX ( ALL ( 'Time to Action' ), 'Time to Action'[timesinceprev] )
```

or rank over `[timesinceprev]`

```
RANKX ( ALL ( 'Time to Action'[timesinceprev] ), 'Time to Action'[timesinceprev] )
```

then you won't get all ones.